# Creating REST api in Databricks which would display delta tables information to the user?

Tags: rest, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-rest-api

I would like to create an API endpoint in Azure Databricks that would publish delta table data to a user. All I found by searching there is no REST API to expose delta table content. Is it true?

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Comment: I could not find any reference to create new api for delta tables.Any reference would be helpful to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just leverage the [Databricks SQL Statement Execution API](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/api/statements.html) to access data on Azure Databricks.  Follow the [tutorial](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/api/sql-execution-tutorial.html) that shows how to work with that API using curl

Answer (score 3):

In Databricks there is no REST Api to get data in delta table, but we can get data of delta table using Databricks jobs.

Follow below steps,

First, create a notebook in databricks which gets data in delta table and returns the data in Json format.
Add below code in your notebook, alter accordingly to your table.

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT  *  FROM test")
j_son = df.toJSON()

res=""
for i in j_son.collect():
    res = res + "," + i

dbutils.notebook.exit("["+res[1:]+"]")
```

Then create a job using this notebook.

[image]

In the next page create the task name, select the path to notebook and your cluster on which it needs to be run.
Then hit on create.

[image]

After creating you will get details as below, copy the job id.

[image]

This is the job in databricks provides API's for running job, getting results of that particular job.

[For more information follow this documentation.](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#)`

Next create an backed server where the API request raised to databricks job.
I've used javascript and expressJs framework.

In visual code open new folder and execute below command in terminal. Make sure you have `nodeJs` installed in your system.

```
npm install express axios cors
```

You will get the project structure as below in your folder.

[image]

Next, create .js file, mine it's `btst.js`.
After creating, add below code in that file.

```
const  express = require('express');
const  axios = require('axios');
const  cors = require('cors');
const  app = express();

app.use(cors({
origin:'*'
}));

const  port = 5000;

// Set the access token for authentication
const  token = 'your databricks token';

// Set the base URL for the Databricks REST API
const  baseUrl = 'https://your databricks host/api/2.1/';

app.get('/runjob', async  function(req, res) {
try {
const  headers = {
'Authorization':  `Bearer ${token}`,
'Content-Type':  'application/json'
}

function  sleep(ms) {
return  new  Promise(resolve  =>  setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const  requestBody = {
job_id:  "1121949406005982"
};
const  response = await  axios.post(`${baseUrl}jobs/run-now/`, requestBody, { headers });
console.log(`run id : ${response.data.run_id}`)
console.log("job is running...")
const  t_res = await  axios.get(`${baseUrl}jobs/runs/get?run_id=${response.data.run_id}`,{ headers })
task_id = t_res.data.tasks[0].run_id
console.log(`task id : ${task_id}`)
await  sleep(15000)
const  d_res = await  axios.get(`${baseUrl}jobs/runs/get-output?run_id=${task_id}`,{ headers })
j_res = JSON.parse(d_res.data.notebook_output.result)
console.log(j_res)
res.send(j_res);
} catch (error) {
console.log(error)
res.status(500).send(`Error1.......${error}`);
}
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Here you paste the job id  you copied earlier in databricks.

[image]
Then execute below command in terminal.

```
node yourfilename.js
```

In my case it is

```
node btst.js
```

Then your server will be running at `http://localhost:5000`.

You send `GET` request to this url in browser or using postman at endpoint.
`http://localhost:5000/runjob`, you will get the data in json format so you can use it anywhere.
This is the below result, it takes 15 seconds to display because after sending post request to jobs it needs to run the task, it takes about 10-15 seconds.
[image]

and data in databricks table is
[image]